# Xcode always builds the project whenever I made any source code change

Tags: ios, xcode, build

I'm using XCode 6.3.2. Recently it has the strange behavior that whenever I make any code change, it automatically builds the project. The build process is so frequent that XCode eats almost all my CPU and drags the computer rather slow. Does anyone have any suggestion how to fix it?

I tried to disable "Show live issues" in the preference but it is the same.

Xcode doesn't behave like this in other projects I have. So I guess it should be because of some project settings. But I don't have any clue where I should start to try out.

In my project it has some pod projects as well.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there a possibility that the Mac has a small amount of RAM and is swapping to virtual often? I saw tjhis on a 4GB RAM Mac with a mid-size project. You might also turn off "Continue building after errors".

Comment: Thanks Zaph. I'm using a 8GB RAM Mac, and also turned off "Continue building after errors". But it is still like that.

Comment: Mine is like that too, nothing works, maybe there is some hidden settings in the build files?

Comment: No solution for this?

Comment: any solution for this??